# How can you print the prime numbers from 0 to 100 in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a small program to find all prime number from a range from 0 to whatever number the user want. How should I fix my code?

I tried to swap the loop position and the algorithm but it didn't work

```
g=int(input("type"))
def check_prime(g):
    if(g<2):
        return False
    for x in range(2, g+1):
        v=int(math.sqrt(x))
        if(x%v==0):
            return False
        return True

if check_prime(g):
 print(x)
```

I expect when the user input `g` they will get all the prime numbers from 0 to `g` and also the program will tell them how many prime numbers found

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, this code below will return you both the count of primes and their values.

```
g=int(input("type"))

def check_prime(g):
  count = 0
  primes = []
  for number in range(g+1): #considering 'g' is inclusive
    primes.append(number)
    count += 1
    if(number < 2 or number%2 == 0):
        primes = primes[:-1]
        count -= 1
        continue
    for x in range(3, number, 2):
      if (number % x) == 0:
        primes = primes[:-1]
        count -= 1
        break

  return count, primes

print (check_prime(g))
```

Comment: What is this line of code mean: " primes = primes[:-1] ". Is it the code to eliminate number which are not prime?

Comment: This line simple removes the latest number added in the primes' list if it's not a prime. It removes the element at the last index basically. You can also use "primes.pop(-1)" instead of that.